# Change VSO user's sign-in address

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-devops

We have a Visual Studio Online account that is backed by an Azure Directory (that is synced from an on-premise Active Directory). For a variety of reasons I won't go into:

- Originally the Azure Directory was synced with accounts in the form "joebloggs@ourdomain.com" (i.e without a dot in the name part).
- VSO invites were sent out to users, using that dot-less form of their address, and we've been using VSO quite happily for a number of months.
- Our infrastructure team now want to use the dotted version of the directory names, so "joe.bloggs@ourdomain.com", within our Azure Directory.

I am trying to find a way to change the sign-in address of all our existing VSO users to be a dotted version of their name. I have been trying to use the 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.Client' libraries to make these changes with code like the following:

```
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Identity.Client;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  UpdateUser();
}

private static void UpdateUser()
{
  var vssAccountUrl = "https://ourVssAccount.vssps.visualstudio.com/";
  var creds = new VssClientCredentials(false);
  var vssConnection = new VssConnection(new Uri(vssAccountUrl), creds);
  var identityClient = vssConnection.GetClient<IdentityHttpClient>();

  var user = identityClient.ReadIdentitiesAsync(IdentitySearchFilter.DisplayName, "Joe Bloggs").Result.FirstOrDefault();
  user.SetProperty("Account", "joe.bloggs@rspb.org.uk");
  user.SetProperty("Mail", "joe.bloggs@rspb.org.uk");

  var t = identityClient.UpdateIdentityAsync(user, null).Result;
  Console.Write(user);
}
```

The call to create a new connection produces a prompt for me to sign in, which I do. I am an admin in the VSO. The call to `UpdateIdentityAsync` though produces the following exception:

`{"Access Denied: Mashton needs the following permission(s) to perform this action: Edit collection-level information"}`

Checking my specific permissions within VSO I *do* have these permissions, as I am an admin for the entire Team Found Server.

Is the exception misleading: does it really need permissions somewhere else?
What is the accepted way to change the sign-in address associated with a VSO user?

Answer (score 0):

Do all dot-less form address have been changed to dotted version of the directory names in your Azure Directory? If the address have been changed in your Azure Directory, you can:

1.Disconnect your account from the directory.

2.Reconnect your account to the directory that you want.

Detailed steps you can refer to https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/setup/manage-organization-access-for-your-account-vs